# How to get the matched return value from find module in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am running an Ansible playbook that looks into a directory and if the size is greater than 1 megabyte, then it has found a match. I just want to verify that it found the correct file. However, I am having a hard time capturing the output. I used the debug module in the documentation, but I still haven't solved it.

```
- hosts: node2 
  tasks: 
    - name: Recursively find /tmp files with last access time greater than 3600 seconds
      find:
        paths: /tmp/myFile/outputs
        size: 1m
        recurse: yes

    - debug:
        matched:
```

I get this error:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.245.61.245]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid options for debug: matched"}
```

Comment: Hi @robert and welcome to SO. If you want to have a good experience on this site, you should be aware that although beginners are more than welcome, most people here will await quite a bit of effort and dedication from you. Actually reading your error messages, researching and reading your tool documentation is part of this. Please have a look at the [`debug` module doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) (where you will see that `matched` is effectively not a `debug` option, but `msg` or `var` are)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the return value of a task to a variable and after that you can print out the variable.

(I slightly modified your code)

```
- hosts: node2 
  tasks: 
    - name: Recursively find /tmp files with last access time greater than 3600 seconds
      find:
        paths: /tmp
        size: 1k
        recurse: yes
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result
```

Here are some useful links, if you want to go more in depth:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html

I hope I could help you :)